# JQuery code in another file

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

before this I wrote all jquery-code into main fail. Now I want to move it into another js-file. The problem is that it doesn't want work correctly.
Here is an error by FireBug:

> $ is not defined
>
> $(document).ready(\n

So, as I understand, I have to initialize $-var... But how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include jQuery before the file that uses it.

Comment: Heh... I have no words :) Thanks.